# chrome://gpu errors and how to fix them

Tags: google-chrome, drivers, video, graphics-card

I am having a lot of issues with choppy videos and I looked at a forum that told me to make sure My Graphics Feature Status were all hardware accelerated. I looked at all my errors and I have a lot of them. How do I fix them? Using 1050TI.

```
**Graphics Feature Status**
Canvas: Hardware accelerated
CheckerImaging: Disabled
Flash: Hardware accelerated
Flash Stage3D: Hardware accelerated
Flash Stage3D Baseline profile: Hardware accelerated
Compositing: Hardware accelerated
Multiple Raster Threads: Enabled
Native GpuMemoryBuffers: Software only. Hardware acceleration disabled
Rasterization: Hardware accelerated
Video Decode: Hardware accelerated
Video Encode: Hardware accelerated
WebGL: Hardware accelerated
WebGL2: Hardware accelerated
```

---

```
**Driver Bug Workarounds**
clear_uniforms_before_first_program_use
decode_encode_srgb_for_generatemipmap
disable_delayed_copy_nv12
disable_discard_framebuffer
disable_dxgi_zero_copy_video
disable_framebuffer_cmaa
exit_on_context_lost
force_cube_complete
scalarize_vec_and_mat_constructor_args
texsubimage_faster_than_teximage
```

---

```
**Problems Detected**
Some drivers are unable to reset the D3D device in the GPU process sandbox
Applied Workarounds: exit_on_context_lost
TexSubImage is faster for full uploads on ANGLE
Applied Workarounds: texsubimage_faster_than_teximage
Clear uniforms before first program use on all platforms: 124764, 349137
Applied Workarounds: clear_uniforms_before_first_program_use
Always rewrite vec/mat constructors to be consistent: 398694
Applied Workarounds: scalarize_vec_and_mat_constructor_args
ANGLE crash on glReadPixels from incomplete cube map texture: 518889
Applied Workarounds: force_cube_complete
Framebuffer discarding can hurt performance on non-tilers: 570897
Applied Workarounds: disable_discard_framebuffer
Use GL_INTEL_framebuffer_CMAA on ChromeOS: 535198
Applied Workarounds: disable_framebuffer_cmaa
Zero-copy NV12 video displays incorrect colors on NVIDIA drivers.: 635319
Applied Workarounds: disable_dxgi_zero_copy_video
Disable KHR_blend_equation_advanced until cc shaders are updated: 661715
Applied Workarounds: disable(GL_KHR_blend_equation_advanced), disable(GL_KHR_blend_equation_advanced_coherent)
Decode and Encode before generateMipmap for srgb format textures on Windows: 634519
Applied Workarounds: decode_encode_srgb_for_generatemipmap
Delayed copy NV12 displays incorrect colors on NVIDIA drivers.: 728670
Applied Workarounds: disable_delayed_copy_nv12
Native GpuMemoryBuffers have been disabled, either via about:flags or command line.
Disabled Features: native_gpu_memory_buffers
Checker-imaging has been disabled via finch trial or the command line.
Disabled Features: checker_imaging
```

Comment: AIUI these are generally expected workarounds (because GPU drivers are often buggy pieces of !@#$) and not a cause for concern. Your problem probably lies elsewhere.